# Very simple program in C not working

Tags: c, printf, scanf

I'm relatively new to coding and am having a problem with a very small piece of code. It seems as if this should be simple to resolve, and I'm bothered that I can't figure it out myself. I was building a program to conduct a variety of conversions that I have to perform all the time and it was ouputting garbage. I backtracked and am testing all my functions. It seems that my functions weren't working, so I began testing each individual function as to whether or not it was correct.

I have one conversion here that I was running as a test code. It should take user int input and calculate ft from an input of miles. That seems pretty simple right? I thought so to.

Can someone please provide some insight as to why the very simple code below doesn't work?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
float miles;
printf("Enter value in miles: ");
scanf(" %d", &miles);
printf("\n\n%.0d miles is equal to %.0d ft.", miles, ((miles)*5280));

return(0);
}
```

Comment: scanf(" %d", &miles); isn't going to work, because %d is asking for an integer, and miles is a float.

Comment: Thanks. I knew it was something remarkably easy. I guess it's too early in the morning. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use %f instead of %d in scanf function

Comment: If you change like this then also replace %f instead of %d in printf function.

Comment: Thanks. I can't believe I missed something so silly. Actually... I guess I can. It works if I change miles to int, but if I change %d to %f as per your recommendation. I get the wrong answer... I get 1073741824 for miles = 2. Any ideas why that might be happening?

Answer (score 1):

You need just an integer. Change

```
float miles;
```

into

```
int miles;
```

Comment: Thanks. I knew it was something silly. That said, why doesn't changing %d to %f as per Rustam's explanation above doesn't return the proper value? I'm fine with using an int for this, but I don't understand why using a float doesn't work. Thanks.

Comment: As long as you are consistent all the way through, either `int and %d` or `float and %f` will work.  Trouble comes when you mix them (w/o appropriate caution).